# capture Ref or custom generate image from JSX/HTML react native without showing UI To user

Tags: react-native, expo, screen-capture

I am wanting to implement a download receipt functionality. I am tyring to use capture Ref because I want to generate a image of receipt that user can download. To generate the image from JSX or html in react native/expo, I use capture Ref. I can only do this with view rendering because this function requires a React component.

```
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/captureRef/
```

but I cannot do this without display the UI to user. What I want to do is, stay on the page, click download button, and have the image downloaded that I can custom create and not show it to the user. But, I cannot quite find a way to just create a image from JSX with content I want in receipt and not show to user. Basically, I want this whole process to happen in background and download to be success.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the content away from the screen with absolute positioning:

```
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', left: Dimensions.get('screen').width}}>
        <ViewShot
          onCapture={onCapture}
          width={width}
          height={height}
        >
          <Text>This will show on the image</Text>
        </ViewShot>
      </View>
```

The lib also provides an example for [offscreen rendering](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot/blob/master/example/Example/src/Offscreen.js)